# Use RFC2217 network serial ports with Twisted Python?

Tags: python, twisted, pyserial, rfc2217

Is there a way to connect to an RFC2217 networked serial port with Twisted Python?

Pyserial seems to support it via the `serial.serial_for_url("rfc2217://...")` [function](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#urls). And they indicate that twisted uses pyserial for managing serial connections, however `twisted.internet.serialport.SerialPort` seems to expect a port name or number which suggests it is just passing this to the `serial.Serial` constructor.

I can use socat to create a PTY externally and pass the dev name to twisted which works fine, but I was wondering if I can bypass this step by using the pyserial support directly.

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/myport TCP:192.168.1.222:9001
```

*Edit*: The [pyserial faq](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/appendix.html#how-to) suggests this modification for instantiating serial objects:

```
try:
    s = serial.serial_for_url(...)
except AttributeError:
    s = serial.Serial(...)
```

Not sure if this helps though...

Comment: I don't have an answer for you I'm afraid; and I suspect the answer is going to be *No; not yet*; and you'd probably want to file an issue :) -- However you've got me thinking that we shoudl also add such a feature to [circuits.io.Serial](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/master/circuits/io/serial.py)

Comment: Thanks James, yes I'll look at filing an issue/feature request if there's no good answer.

Comment: WRT to your edit; I think you would want to do ``if "://" in``. i.e: test for a URI or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that using Pyserial's RFC2217 support with Twisted Python is non-trivial. Pyserial's implementation of RFC2217, besides [being currently experimental](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#rfc-2217-network-ports), uses threads to manage the socket connection which they state as being a problem for select based applications:

> The current implementation starts a thread that keeps reading from the (internal) socket. The thread is managed automatically by the rfc2217.Serial port object on open()/close(). However it may be a problem for user applications that like to use select instead of threads.

It is fairly straight forward to subclass t.i.serialport.SerialPort and overwrite the _serialFactory method (which creates the pyserial object to be used for accessing the serial port)

```
class SerialPort(serialport.SerialPort):
    def _serialFactory(self, dev, *args, **kwargs):
        " pyserial recommends the following for supporting serial urls "
        try:
            return serial.serial_for_url(dev)
        except AttributeError:
            return serial.Serial(dev, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, the resulting object lacks a file descriptor and so the `fileno()` method (used internally by `t.i._posixserialport`) throws an exception.

```
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1204, in mainLoop
    self.doIteration(t)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 105, in doSelect
    [], timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_posixserialport.py", line 48, in fileno
    return self._serial.fd
exceptions.AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

The current workarounds are to either use `socat` as described in the question, or for the network serial server I'm using (Brainboxes ES-842) you can configure it in "Raw TCP" mode instead of "Telnet/RFC2217" mode and just use your existing protocol over a TCP connection (as long as you're not depending on flow control or other serial control lines and can use a predefined fixed baud rate).